How to "easily" calculate the limits and sections of convolution integral?
We started recently talking in my signal processing class about the convolution integral, and in theory, it sounds easy enough but now after a few exercises I realize I either don't know the technique needed to find the limits of the integral (since you usually need to consider different cases for your integral limits)
for example with the following function $a(t)=\begin{cases}1& |t|\leq0.5\\0& \text{o.w.}\end{cases}$ , first I transform this into a function $a(t)=u(t+0.5)-u(t-0.5)$ and now for the convolution itself: $$\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}a\left(t-\tau\right)a\left(\tau\right)d\tau=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u\left(t+0.5-\tau\right)-u\left(t-0.5-\tau\right)\right)\left(u\left(\tau+0.5\right)-u\left(\tau-0.5\right)\right)d\tau$$
$$\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}u\left(t+0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau+0.5\right)-u\left(t+0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau-0.5\right)-u\left(t-0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau+0.5\right)+u\left(t-0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau-0.5\right)d\tau$$
we end up with 4 different integrals and for each of those I need to calculate what values of $t$ will result in one lower limit and upper limit, now don't get me wrong, it's doable but I feel like I'm taking the hard way to solve it.
just for example, this is what I currently do:
$$\begin{cases}
u\left(t+0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau+0.5\right) & \Rightarrow\left(\tau\geq-0.5\right)\land\left(\tau\leq t+0.5\right)\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\min=t+0.5 & t<-1\\
\min=-0.5 & t>-1
\end{cases}\\
u\left(t+0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau-0.5\right) & \Rightarrow\left(\tau\geq0.5\right)\land\left(\tau\leq t+0.5\right)\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\min=t+0.5 & t<0\\
\min=0.5 & t>0
\end{cases}\\
u\left(t-0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau+0.5\right) & \Rightarrow\left(\tau\geq-0.5\right)\land\left(\tau\leq t-0.5\right)\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\min=t+0.5 & t<0\\
\min=-0.5 & t>0
\end{cases}\\
u\left(t-0.5-\tau\right)u\left(\tau-0.5\right) & \Rightarrow\left(\tau\geq0.5\right)\land\left(\tau\leq t-0.5\right)\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\min=t+0.5 & t<1\\
\min=0.5 & t>1
\end{cases}
\end{cases}$$
and this takes me a few minutes to setup and is very error-prone, now I also need to construct the revised integrals with the limits and the $t$ values...
how I see it now, for each separate expression I need to do 2 comparisons in both the upper and lower limit so that ends up in 4 comparisons (which aren't instantaneous for me) and that's still when only having 2 step functions in an integral expression, I imagine things will get much more complicated.
is there a way to go directly from the piece-wise representation of the function to the piecewise representation of the convolution? or some method/technique to solve those more quickly/easily?

Are there alternatives but conceptually are more advanced than the convolutions itself, so surely you will learned from them later on your signals course: specifically, you could transform the convolutions into multiplications throw the Fourier Transform

Here is a graphical method that provides a quick way to check your work.
If $f(s)$ is nonzero only  on the interval $s\in I_f$ and $g(t)$ is nonzero only on an interval $t\in I_g$ then you can draw a rectangle $R$ in the $(s,t)$ plane ( defined by the Cartesian product $R=I_f\times I_g$).
Note that  the convolution formula can be written as $$(f*g)(x)= \int_{\{s+t=x\}\cap R} f(s) g(t) ds$$
The limits of integration in  $s$ can be inferred by checking where the line $s+t=x$ hits the boundary of the rectangle.
Thus, sketch the family of 45-degree lines $s+t=x$, especially  looking for the values of $x$ at which such lines hit the rectangle's corners. That is where the limits of integration abruptly change character.
Example 1. Suppose $I_f= I_g=[-1,1]$. Then the Cartesian product is a square whose four vertices are  $(s,t)=(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1).$
The special values of $x=s+t$ at these four vertices are $x=-2,0,0,2$.
Let's see how the convolution limits of integration depend on values of $x$.
Case 1. ($x=0$). Consider first the special value $x=0$. The equation $s+t=0$ defines the diagonal of the square. Thus $t=-s$ on this particular line. Projecting that red segment onto the horizontal $S$ axis, you see that its limits are $s=-1$ and $s=1$. Thus you find that when $x=0$, the convolution integral is expressible as $(f*g)(x|_{x=0})=\int_{s=-1}^{s=1} f(s) g(-s) ds$.
Case 2. For any generic value of $x$ like $x=-1.5\in[-2,0]$ you can see that the line $s+t=x$ intersects the square in a short (green) segment. The segment lies in the lower left half of the square.  Its projection on the horizontal $s$ axis represents the limits of integration in that $s$ variable.
The limits of integration are given by $-1<s<x+1$. The lower value of $s$ corresponds to the left vertical edge of the square. The upper limit of integration corresponds to the bottom edge of the square. That limit was found by using $s+t=x$ and substituting  the edge value $t=-1$ to get $s=x+1$.
Case 3. The upper right half of the square corresponds to larger values of $x$.

This method is a bit tedious but always provides a quick visual check on the overall structure of the limits of integration.
When checking your tentative work, try setting $x$ equal to a handful of special values, and seeing if the limits of integration  match up with the diagram correctly.
P.S. The same idea works even when say $f$ is nonzero on two separate intervals, (and the same for $g$). (This case occurs when we have two signals $f$ and $g$, each of which pulses on and off twice in succession.)
Here is a picture of one such example. It breaks down into four distinct rectangles, each of which can be analyzed separately, and then the results combined.  In such complicated cases, the geometric diagram becomes especially useful.
In this example there are 16 vertices, and therefore potentially as many as 16 distinct special values of $x$ where abrupt changes occur. (Or fewer if ties accidentally occur.)
(Apologies that the red line is drawn crookedly, not perfectly at 45 degrees. Its intercepts, if drawn correctly, should of course match.)


sorry, but i don't quite understand the procedure you described, I understood only up to the different (but equivalent) definition of the convolution.
also didn't quite understand the plot you shared, (I think) I get that each intersection area of the rectangles corresponds to integral limits where its values run on both axis, but didn't quite understand the redline and how to extract the limits for the integrals.

Updated with more details.
